# What happens if different region attribute values are specified on parent and child?

Tags: ttml

Suppose we have the following TTML document:

```
<tt xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling">
  <head>
    <layout>
      <region xml:id="a"/>
      <region xml:id="b"/>
    </layout>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div region="a">
      <p region="b">abc</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</tt>
```

According to [9.3.2 Intermediate Synchronic Document Construction](http://www.w3.org/TR/ttml1/#semantics-region-layout-step-1), what visual marks will be produced by regions `a` and `b`?

At first I was expecting `a` to produce nothing and `b` to produce *abc*, but the specification seems to contradict this implying that the anonymous span *abc* will be pruned (directly or indirectly) both when evaluating region `a` and `b`, which seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm prunes the content and nothing is displayed. This is captured on the W3C TTWG Issue tracker in [Issue-341](https://www.w3.org/AudioVideo/TT/tracker/issues/341).

Why would you author a document with this behaviour though - I mean, what would you intend to happen? Under which conditions would you not achieve the same thing simply by removing the region reference from the div? I ask for interest - if there's a use case here then we can use it to help drive the spec development in TTML.

Comment: At first I thought it could be useful to assign a whole `div` to a region using the region attribute, and then single descendants of that `div` could be "taken out" of the region and put in a different one. But after considering this for a while I got to the realization that this could lead to creation of invalid structure of elements in ISD (for example `span` being placed directly in a `region`) so it seems I understand the reason the spec defines the algorithm this way now. Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering if it would be better (for the spec) to completely disallow the use of `region` attribute for elements which already have an ancestor with a specified region, since using the `region` attribute on such elements is equivalent to setting `tts:display` to `none` and that seems a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: That rule could work - in TTML2 it will be a bit more complex because anonymous inline regions can be specified by putting tts:origin and tts:extent attributes for example directly on content elements. But the same general idea can apply.